# Gridview textbox focus gets postback

Tags: gridview, postback, textchanged

Am using gridview textchaged event for multiply two textbox values in this by entering value in Textbox1 and press tab by focusing to Textbox2, form gets postback i applied update panel between gridview but its not worked give solution to this.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uvXet.jpg)

Comment: please provide your aspx & .cs code.

Comment: <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="BOQ Quantity">
 <ItemTemplate>
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox3" class="form-control1" runat="server" ontextchanged="TextBox3_TextChanged" AutoPostBack="true"></asp:TextBox>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
 <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Rate">
<ItemTemplate>
<asp:TextBox ID="TxtRate" class="form-control1" runat="server" ontextchanged="TxtRate_TextChanged" AutoPostBack="true"></asp:TextBox>
</ItemTemplate>
 </asp:TemplateField>

Comment: TextBox3_TextChanged
if(TextRate.Text=="" || TextQuantity.Text=="")
{ TextAmt.Text=""; TextRate.Focus();}
else{TextAmt.Text = (float.Parse(TextQuantity.Text) * float.Parse(TextRate.Text)).ToString(); TextRate.Focus();}

Comment: Set the update mode property of update panel to Always.

<asp:UpdatePanel ID="updPnl" runat="server" UpdateMode="Always">

Comment: yes i set that then also its getting postback if i remove TextBox.Focus() its working fine. but i need to focus on next textbox after enterning value in first textbox

Comment: Try this.
<Triggers>
  <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="txtboxid" EventName="TextChanged" >
</Triggers>
or 
try this
ScriptManager1.SetFocus(TextBox);

Comment: am using dynamic gridview if i add <Triggers> with ControlID am getting error as "txtboxid" could not be found for the trigger in UpdatePanel

Comment: have you use  ScriptManager1.SetFocus(TextBox);??

Comment: No am not used ScriptManager1.SetFocus(TextBox);

Comment: without
<asp:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="server">
        </asp:ToolkitScriptManager>
update panel will not work

Comment: i added toolscriptmanager and added two update panel one for overall form and another one for gridview

Comment: pelase provide me your whole code.